# SpringBoot Autowired only works with embedded Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, vaadin, autowired

I have a `Spring Boot / Vaadin 14` application that is really causing me to scratch my head.  I've done this a thousand times but cannot seem to find what I am missing.

When I run the app with the embedded Tomcat (`spring-boot:run`), everything works.  But when I run it using an external Tomcat 9 (on my same machine), my autowired dependencies are null.

My code:

**AppConfig.java**

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.example.myapp")
@EnableVaadin
public class AppConfig implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2113829779705972298L;
}
```

**Vaadin ETL View:**

```
@Route(value = "etl", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("ETL")
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = MainView.class)
public class EtlView extends Div implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6417032793665450391L;

    @Autowired
    private AsyncRestClientService service;   // this works with embedded.  NULL with external.
    ...
```

**AsyncRestClientService:**

```
@Service
public class AsyncRestClientService implements Serializable {
    ...
```

**MyApplication:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyAppApplication .class, args);
    }

}
```

All classes are in the `com.example.myapp` package so the component scan should pick this up.
Any ideas what I am missing?

BTW, I am doing the exact same thing with a Vaadin 8 application and everything works.  Even with my external Tomcat 9.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Note, I am packaging this as a `WAR` in my pom.xml.

Comment: maybe you should: class MyAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer

Comment: @9dan that worked.  But I am stumped as to why?  Would you mind forming that as an answer with maybe a brief description?  I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto-traditional-deployment

Comment: Did you build production mode app for deploying to external Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to package the app as a WAR instead of JAR when deploying a Spring Boot app to an external Tomcat. Check this out: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that.  I am packaging as a WAR.  I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Did you changed `<packaging>`, add `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and, extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`? AFAIK all these are required to package a Spring Boot app as a WAR.